Using Apache POI, while creating a PowerPoint presentation using XMLSlideShow, how do I add image within a paragraph?
The Apache POI cookbook and various other examples talk about directly adding a picture in PowerPoint as shown below -
XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();
ppt.createSlide();
byte[] pictureData = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream("logo-leaf.png"));

XSLFPictureData pd
= ppt.addPicture(pictureData, PictureData.PictureType.PNG);
XSLFPictureShape picture = slide.createPicture(pd);
picture.setAnchor(new Rectangle(320, 230, 100, 92));


And this works very much as expected.
What I need is a paragraph to show a user profile image next to name and address repeated as per the data -
.
This is similar to what we generally view in a social media pages shown in image above which can extend across slides.
I tried but could find relevant methods in XSLFShape.
May be there could be a better way to render this rather than using a paragraph. Any code block, pointers appreciated.

I do not understand the reason for the downvote because I could not find any methods in XSLFShape to do so, neither any working example to include a picture within a shape.

PowerPoint itself doesn't allow inserting an image into the middle of a paragraph, so there won't be a way to automate it from outside PowerPoint. There might be a way of doing this with a table, but inserting pictures into table cells tends to distort the pictures unless they and the cell are in the same proportions. Your best bet is probably to insert individual shapes for each block of text and corresponding image.

You may want to create group shapes that group a text box and an image shape.
Example:
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils; 

import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class CreatePPTXGroupShape {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
  Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
   new Object[] {"Koala", IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream("./Koala.png"))},
   new Object[] {"Squirrel", IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream("./Squirrel.png"))},
   new Object[] {"Fox", IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream("./Fox.png"))}
  };

  SlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow();

  Slide slide = slideShow.createSlide();
  
  int groupLeft = 100;
  int groupTop = 50;
  int groupWidth = 250;
  int groupHeight = 100;
  int groupPadding= 10;
  
  for (Object[] row : data) {
   GroupShape shapeGroup = slide.createGroup();
   shapeGroup.setInteriorAnchor(new Rectangle(groupLeft, groupTop, groupWidth, groupHeight));
   shapeGroup.setAnchor(new Rectangle(groupLeft+groupPadding, groupTop+groupPadding, groupWidth-groupPadding, groupHeight-groupPadding));
 
   int x = groupLeft;
   int y = groupTop;
   int width = 100;
   int height = 100;

   TextShape textShape = shapeGroup.createTextBox();
   Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
   textShape.setAnchor(rect);
   String text = (String)row[0];
   textShape.setText(text);

   x = groupLeft + 150;
   y = groupTop;
   width = 100;
   height = 100;

   byte[] pictureDataByte = (byte[])row[1];
   PictureData pictureData = slideShow.addPicture(pictureDataByte, PictureData.PictureType.PNG);
   PictureShape pictureShape = shapeGroup.createPicture(pictureData);
   rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
   pictureShape.setAnchor(rect);

   groupTop += 110;
  
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreatePPTXGroupShape.pptx");
  slideShow.write(out);
  out.close();
 }
}

Result:


Appreciate to explain the usages of GroupShape with a complete working example. After I posted the question, I was trying with XSLFTable, but couldn't get the solution working. Thank you @Axel.
